# How to execute Wolfram Language code/scripts in R Studio (or similar)?

Tags: scripting

How to execute the Wolfram Language in R Studio?, or similar.

https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/?source=nav

Answer (score 2):

https://notebookarchive.org/calling-wolfram-language-from-r--2022-01-62ta27f/

Perhaps this link and notebook might help.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).